# Upload zip files in angular 8

Tags: html, angular, typescript, file-upload, angular8

I am trying to implement zip file upload functionality in Angular 8 app. 3 conditions that I need to satisfy are:

```
1. Only allow zip files to be uploaded else throw error message
2. File size should not cross 3 MBs else throw error message
3. When I choose zip file, it should show progress bar but file should only be uploaded via REST API call when I click 'Register' button separately.
```

What I  have implemented so far is:**File Upload Service**

```
postFile(fileToUpload: File, header): Observable<any> {
    const endpoint = 'your-destination-url';
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('fileKey', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
    if (fileToUpload.size <= 3048576)
    return this.httpClient.post(endpoint, formData, { headers: header })
      .pipe(map(data => {
        console.log(data);
        return data;
      },error => {
        console.log(error, 'reduce file size');
      })) 
    }
```

**Component TS File**

```
handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
this.fileToUpload = files.item(0);
}
uploadFileToActivity() {
  this.fileUploadService.postFile(this.fileToUpload, this.headers).subscribe(data => {
    // do something, if upload success
    console.log('the file has been uploaded successfully', data);
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

**Component HTML**

```
<input type="file"
 id="file" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">
```

Please suggest how can I modify so that my functionality is as described.

Answer (score 0):

for points 1 and 2 you should add a validation function in your code to check both the file extension and the size.
The upload should be possible only if the file passes the validation.
In addition to that, you should probably return some kind of feedback to the user when the validation fails.

You can track the file upload progress (and show a progress bar) adding additional options to the .post method and listening for specific events

```
return this.httpClient.post(endpoint, formData, { 
 headers: header,
 reportProgress: true, 
 observe: 'events'
}).pipe(map(event => {  
 if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
  // upload complete
 }
 if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {    
  // the event contains information about loaded data
  // you can use event.loaded and event.total to display the progress bar
 }
}))
```